# how can I change svn folder to normal folder

Tags: git, svn

In git I can remove `.git` folder and after that, the folder is considered as a normal folder, I wonder how can I do the same for svn folder?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same, but svn creates a hidden .svn folder for each subfolders (for older SVN versions).

Newer svn clients also only create a single top-level `.svn` directory.

In both cases, just remove .svn in the parent, and in the subfolders if exists on your version.

Comment: Newer svn clients also only create a single top-level `.svn` directory. (but this answer still applies)

Comment: Good to know. I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `svn export`: this will create a clean (without any `.svn` folder) copy of your svn working copy. You can choose to export only the svn-versioned files or also other files that are being ignored.

After *exporting* you can just remove the original working copy folders. Make sure that all the critical files are there (you may have forgotten to add them).